# Sharepoint data returned as NULL instead of a number in Tableau?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise

We have a SharePoint connection through Tableau and for some reason all the other data comes in fine but one column comes in as all NULL values when I know that data is a double with values in most of the fields.

Column of data in the SharePoint site shows values:

[image]

When reviewing the data in Tableau the values are all Null:

[image]

Another odd thing is that we cannot preview the data in Tableau data source tab.
The option to select the preview data is grayed out and I have never had this happen before.
Maybe its a issue with SharePoint data as I have never connected to SharePoint before with Tableau.

[image]

Unfortunately I cannot provide more data. It is confidential.

Has anyone run into this problem before?

So far all the research I have found has returned nothing useful.

Comment: How about you try to repro the problem with another list with dummy data and post screenshots of that?

Comment: @teylyn I don't actually know how to use SharePoint. Never created a site or built any data into one. I just gather information from a data source and build dashboards from them. I don't see any reason why some data would be fine but others columns would be all null. It just seams like a strange problem to have. I have connected using Access to this data and it works fine. I have also connected to the SharePoint site using OData and that works fine. But directly connection from Tableau produces this odd problem.